# How to select values and organize into a new table in sql/oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle, sorry if this is too basic.

```
T1:
ID_SET ID
1      10
1      11
2      12
2      13
T2:

ID    Term
11    LONG
12    SHORT
```

I have tables T1 and T2, i want to select from both tables and insert into another table T3  which will be:

```
T3
Long_term Short_term  ID_SET
Long                    1
          Short         2
```

So for a given ID_SET, check if the ID's in this ID_SET contains 'Long' or 'Short'.
Insert into T3 in the corresponding columns. The ID_SET can only contain one of 'Long' and 'Short'. I try full/right/left join, but can't get it worked..

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: use an "insert into" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
insert into t3 (Long_term, Short_term, ID_SET)
select
  t2long.term,
  t2short.term,
  t1.id_set
from t1
left join t2 t2long on t1.id = t2long.id and t2long.term = 'Long'
left join t2 t2short on t1.id = t2short.id and t2short.term = 'Short';
```